# Struggling with basic facts about schemes. Questions regarding open subsets of schemes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, definition, schemes

This is data I am thinking about after reading sections 1,2,3 of chapter 2 on schemes from Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*.

*Basically, I know very little and I'm very uncomfortable with schemes.*

---

---

Let $X$ be a scheme.

We know that every point is in some open affine $U_i \cong \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)$. So, we can cover $X$ be open affines $U_i \cong \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)$.

Now, we can intersect any open subset of $X$ with the cover of open affines.

(1) **Does this mean that any open subset of $X$ be can covered (abusing notation) by basic open subsets $D(f_{i_j}) \subset \operatorname{Spec}(A_i)$? Therefore, any point in $X$ is in some (abusing notation) $D(f_{i_j}) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(A_{i_{f_{i_j}}})$?**

---

An exercise shows that any open subset is a scheme via the induced scheme structure.

(2) **Does this mean that any cover of $X$ will give us a cover by open affines?** For example, take any open subset $U$. Then $U$ is a scheme via the induced scheme structure. So, we can cover $U$ via open affines. **Since $U$ is open, then these open affines are also open affines of $X$?**

---

(3) If $p \in X$ is in some open affine $U \cong \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, **can we also keep finding smaller and smaller open affines containing $p$? How do these smaller and smaller open affines relate to $U$ and $X$? How do the rings relate to each other?**

Comment: (1): yes. (2): yes. Note that affine-ness for an open subset $U$ of the scheme $X$ doesn’t depend on $X$, apart from $X$ defining the structure sheaf on $U$. (3): theoretically, yes (if you allow for equalities). But beware, the topology on a scheme isn’t like a Euclidean topology – Zariski open subsets are relatively scarce. In important special cases (local rings, fields) it’s possible that $U$ is a *minimal* open subset containing $p$ (ie there is no smaller one). This being said, in many examples you still have enough cases to restrict the open subset further.

Comment: As an aside, I think Vakil does a *much* better job than Hartshorne at describing how to communicate between affine opens of a scheme. If you're still feeling a bit shaky on this, I heartily recommend reading section 5.3 of [his book](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) (p. 157). A key result not mentioned in Hartshorne is [Nike's trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57077/), which Vakil then uses to prove what he calls the Affine Communication Lemma. Both of these are incredibly useful for combining affine local data on several affine opens.

Comment: I've improved the formatting of your post by replacing $Spec$ ("Spec") with $\operatorname{Spec}$ ("\operatorname{Spec}"), which produces better spacing and is more readable. Please keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @Mindlack that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: @RichardD.James I just skimmed some of that section. Thanks. So, (abusing notation) we can say that a basis for $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is $\{ \operatorname{Spec}(A_f) \}_{f \in A}$?

Comment: Yes, with the usual identifications $\operatorname{spec}(A_f)\hookrightarrow \operatorname{spec}(A)$, this is true

Comment: @AlekosRobotis Thanks. And then what would basic open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec}(A_f)$ look like?

Comment: Further localizations. E.g. $\operatorname{spec}(A_{fg})$. That is, we think of this part of the spectrum as being those points where the functions $f$ and $g$ are invertible, e.g. nonvanishing. This corresponds to the intuitive idea of taking the complement of subvarieties in affine space in the classical case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1): yes, exactly.

(2): yes. Note that affine-ness for an open subset $U$ of the scheme $X$ doesn’t depend on $X$ itself, only on $U$, apart from $X$ defining the structure sheaf on $U$.

(3): theoretically, yes (if you allow for equalities).
The property is the following: if $U$ is any open subset of a scheme and $p \in U$, there exists an affine open subset $p \in W \subset U$.

But beware, the topology on a scheme isn’t like a Euclidean topology – Zariski open subsets are relatively scarce. In important special cases (local rings, fields) it’s possible that $U$ is a minimal open subset containing $p$, (that is, there is no smaller one). It’s also (that’s rather the opposite phenomenon) possible that any nonempty open subset $U$ contains $p$. This being said, in many examples, you still have enough cases to restrict the open subset further.

Note that it’s rarely useful to ask for a strict restriction – most early algebraic phenomena can be appropriately studied through Zariski open subsets.